# Why do ladies pray differently as per Hanafi fiqh?

Tags: salat, women, hanafi

In Sahih Bukhari, Our Prophet Sallallaho Alaihewasallam (peace be upon him) said "Pray as you have seen me to pray". He didn't shown any different way to pray for ladies. Why ladies are praying differently as per Hanafi fiqh?

Comment: It would be nice if you could let us know where this difference you mentioned is!

Answer (score 5):

As a new Muslim, I learned how to pray from [a YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7ZySx-TMeY) entitled *Women's prayer according to Qur'an and Sunnah*.  Turns out, I learned how to pray from a cute Hanafi girl.  The video answers your question, and even addresses the exact hadith you mention:

> Some claim the hadith "pray as you have seen me praying" applies to women, however this is incorrect.  The Prophet (pbuh) was "seen" praying with a turban, with his ankles exposed, leading men in prayer, etc.
>
> Does that mean that women should do this as well?  No.

It continues:

> [Imam Baihaqi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Bayhaqi) says, 'all of the laws of salah in which a woman differs from a man are based on the principle of satr (concealment).  This means that the woman is instructed to do all that which is more concealing for her.'  Baihaqi 2/314.

Throughout the video, it gives step-by-step instructions and relevant references.  For example:

> Yazid bin Abi Habib reports that the Prophet (pbuh) passd by two women who were praying salah, he said, "When you prostrate, let part of your body cling to the earth, for women are unlike men in this regard".  Abu Dawood in his Al Maraseel PL8 (Muassasah al Risalah edition), and Baiha 3201.

([AskImam.org](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/15154) write: "The first hadith is a [mursal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology#Mursal) narration.  All the narrators in it are reliable.  Mursal narrations are accepted by the Hanafi Jurists.")  and

> Ibrahim (rah) said: When a woman goes in sajdah she should join the thighs to her stomach and also not raise her posterior and also "not stretch her limbs out like a male" [Mussanaf ibn Abi Shaybah (1/303)]

A detailed fatwa [Why is a Woman’s sajdah different to men?](http://efiqh.com/2012/why-is-a-womans-sajdah-different-to-men/) by  Mufti Luqman Hansrot includes these hadith along with other sources.

Comment: Al-Baihaqi is a shafi'i, but AFAIK in the hanafi madhab there's even a difference between how women pray in other madhabs, therefore I was hoping for an elaboration, but maybe that's somewhat wrong (as -the apparently- main difference is on allowing the feet to be uncovered is well known). Your answer at least answers the given question and might be enlightening for those who forgot that women need to cover themselves during the prayer ;)

Comment: Please note that the hadiths mentioned are not authentic. Abu Dawood's Al Maraseel is a collection of hadiths with severed chains ([mursal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadith_terminology)). Mussanaf ibn Abi Shaybah on this topic is athars, not hadiths. As for Baihaqi 2/314, the complete quote is: Abu Ahmad said 'Umar ibn Abi-'Umar is unknown and I do not know anything else attributed to him apart from 'all of the laws of salah ...".

Comment: @Rebecca Ma sha Allah very well written answer with references.

Answer (score 5):

> Pray as you have seen me to pray

My understanding is that Ar-Rasool (SAWS) made this statement in the company of his male companions. It was an order to them (all men), there were no women present. It cannot be applied to women. There are differences as Sister Rebecca points out.

This question shows why it is important to study the Quran and Hadith with a teacher, and to study them in context, otherwise you can easily come to incorrect conclusions.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between the way Men and women Pray, and what some of the Madhahib say in regards to the difference, [there is no authentic/or there is no evidence supporting it](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/mat/877).  And the Hadith you mentioned in your question refers to all, both men and women.

Sources: [binbaz.com (In Arabic)](http://www.binbaz.org.sa/mat/877).